# Html table add and delete rows dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, innerhtml

I want to have a table with no rows initially and after that to create each row dynamically and also to be able to delete every row.
I got **Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined**
Please let me know how it should be done,
Thank you.

```js
function addRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
  cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
  try {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      var row = table.rows[i];
      var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];

      table.deleteRow(i);
      rowCount--;
      i--;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Click the button to add a new row at the first position of the table and then add cells and content.</p>

  <table id="myTable">
    <TR>

    </TR>
  </table>
  <br>

  <button type="button" onclick="addRow()">Add</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="deleteRow('myTable')">Delete</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The table is named `myTable`, not `tableData`.

Comment: What @Barmar said, then edit this line: `table.deleteRow(row);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button type="button" onclick="deleteRow('myTable')">Delete</button>
```

Just had the wrong table id being passed in.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined with right table id.

Comment: @Cameron121341 sounds like a different problem for another question